# SOQL query to get the first and last day of the current month?

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, soql-injection, async-soql

i need to pass SOQL query to get the first and last day of the previous month.

Example Query:
Select Name, ID
FROM Audit__C
WHERE Audit_Month__C BETWEEN 'previous month start date (2020-04-01)' AND 'previous month end date (2020-04-30)'

i will be passing today's date in both the date area. which SOQL date function helps me in getting previous month first date and last date while passing today's date?

Answer (score 2):

You can use LAST_MONTH date literal like this:

```
Select Name, ID FROM Audit__C WHERE Audit_Month__C = LAST_MONTH
```

From documentation:

> Starts 00:00:00 on the first day of the month before the current day and continues for all the days of that month.

More info on date literals: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm